# ArcGIS Flex Viewer charts widget

Tags: arcgis-flex-viewer, chart, widget

I have a problem with the Charts widget.
I try to represent rainfall following the month of the year by stations.

To display the widget mixture Charts month. There is a problem with the order of the bars of the charts.
There is no logic, following stations.

Examples:

station 1
August / February / December / etc ...

station 2
November / January / May / October / etc ...

Anyone know how to fix this problem ?